# IE7 making text longer than it should be

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html-table

Firstly, the code:

```
<tr>
  <td width="610" 
     style="font-family:Verdana, 
            Geneva, sans-serif;
            text-decoration:none !important; 
            font-size: 9px; 
            color: #231F20;margin:0px;  
            padding:0px; margin-right:10px;">
    <span style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; 
                 text-decoration:none !important;  
                 font-size: 1em; color: #231F20; 
                 margin-right:10px;">
      CancerFactsFigures&#47;BreastCancerFactsFigures&#47;
      breast-cancer
     -facts-and-figures-2011-2012. Accessed June 6, 2012.
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

My problem is that this code wraps around to a new row in IE7 and IE8.  I've compared it to other browsers and I can tell that there is extra spacing the builds up throughout the entire line that causes it to eventually spill over.

This is all set in a table with a width of 600.  Yes, I know my TD width is set to 610, I was just messing around to see if I could trick IE.

Updated code to only have 1 span, but the problem didn't go away.

What's going on?  I'm stumped.

Comment: You have one extra </span>

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by font rendering variation, specifically by the differences between IE 9 and older versions of IE, see [About Text Rendering in Windows Internet Explorer 9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh237264%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You should design your code so that the layout does not depend on the details of rendering, such as the exact width occupied by some piece of text. Avoid setting fixed widths on table cells, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You have one extra `</span>`